# How to call a function to an element dynamically loaded by Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails, gsp

I'm trying to use the jQuery Plugin SelectBoxIt, but my content is loaded by Ajax, and I'm not getting it to work.

I'm using Grails and I don't wanna put inline code, so I've tried to load it with the .on() jQuery method, but I can't get it since I don't want to put an event, I just want it to load when my content loads, and I can't find another solution.

I'm trying to do something like this:

My page calls  a remote link:

```
<g:remoteLink controller="strategy" action="index" update="content-box"></g:remoteLink>
```

Then, ALL my HTML selects must trigger the plugin and turn from normal selects to the ones the plugin provides:

```
$(document).on('click', 'select', function(){
    $('select').selectBoxIt()
})
```

But I don't want to trigger them with the click event, I want them to trigger right when the page is called.

Since my content is not added when the first page loads, I thought the .on() method was the right choice, but it makes me put an event, and I want to trigger when the page loads()

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use the callback function? Please show us your ajax code.

Comment: Attach it right after your insert the new content into the DOM. No need of `.on()` here.

Comment: @Bergi - The ajax call is made automatically by Grails and the page renders.

Comment: @techfoobar - But to do that, I must invoke the method in EVERY page that have a HTML select element, and I want to construct for all the selects that I must have in the future.

Comment: @AndréBuzzo is there a callback function that is available from Grails? If not, you'll have a hard time.

Comment: @AndréBuzzo - In that case, you'll be better off using a taglib and rendering the special selects using it. the taglib can auto-insert the script where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe read this, http://api.jquery.com/load/ and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. Sorry I can't be of more help.